# k-means for many same points in R

Tags: r, k-means

Suppose I have a one dimension data set, which contains many same numbers, for example data set `S = c(rep(4, times(1000)), rep(5, times(808)), rep(9, times(990)))`. Is there any efficient ways to do k-means in R? Actually in my data I have just a around 20 different points, but each of them appears around 100000 times, it runs very slow. So I wonder if there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-means can be implemented with **weights**. It's straightforward to do so.

But IIRC the version included with R is not implemented this way. The version on `flexcluster` *maybe* is, but it's pure R and much much much slower.

Either way, you will want to implement this in Fortran or C, like the regular kmeans version. Maybe you can find some package that has a good implementation already.

Comment: Thank you. I find a function kmeansW {FactoClass}, which works well.